# Creating an asymmetric multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays

### Context

I have not yet found a generalized question about how to create an "asymmetric*" multi dimensional array in python. *With asymmetric I mean that some elements that are arrays themselves, vary in their lengths.

### attempt 0

```
second_dim = [1,2]
second_dim[0] = [1,5] 
second_dim[1] = [1,5,9]
list = [ [ [ [ '' for i in range(2) ] for j in range(len(second_dim[i])) ] for k in range(5) ] for l in range(6) ]
```

Note that this yields error: `undefined name i`

### Question

How would one construct such^ an array in python using parameters?

^Suppose:

- dimension 0 has length `a = 2`
- the first element of dimensions 0 has length `b = 2`
- the second element of dimensions 0 has length `c = 3`
- dimension 2 has length 5 dimension 4 has length `d = 5`
- dimension 3 has length 5 dimension 4 has length `e = 6`

Comment: post expected output

Comment: You are creating a list, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

I am really not sure what you have meant by the example, but this might help.

If you define your desired dimensions in a list like this:

```py
dims = [ 
  [4, 5],
  [5, 6, 2],
]
```

You can use a very simple recursive function:

```py
def make_dims(dims, fill_func=int):
  if isinstance(dims, int):
    return [fill_func() for _ in range(dims)]
  return [make_dims(x, fill_func) for x in dims]

l = make_dims(dims)
```

to create the list list with that has "dimensions" like this:

```py
len(l) == len(dims) == 2
len(l[0]) == len(dims[0]) == 2
len(l[0][0]) == dims[0][0]) == 4
len(l[0][1]) == dims[0][1]) == 5
len(l[1]) == len(dims[1]) == 3
len(l[1][0]) == dims[1][0] == 5
len(l[1][1]) == dims[1][1] == 6
len(l[1][2]) == dims[1][2] == 2
```

and all the last level elements being whatever is returned by the `fill_func()` producer.

---

For your example `second_dim = [[1, 5], [1, 5, 9]]` calling `make_dims(second_dim)` just works right out of the box.

However, if you are sure you don't need the flexibility with more dimensions this solution provides and you insist on using list comprehension, your "attempt 0" isn't too far off. However, you just need to better keep track what values are processing:

```py
[[[0 for _ in range(y)] for y in x] for x in second_dim]
```